# Error 404 cuando accedo a http://localhost:5000

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, mongodb, express

Estoy realizando un proyecto en MERN Stack y al realizar la petición a la Api me devuelve error 404.

No se que puede ser ya que el servidor funciona correctamente, lo raro es que a veces al levantarlo si que funciona sin tocar nada pero otras veces no y no se como solucionarlo.

Otro dato curioso es que al levantar los servidores de otros proyectos que si que funcionaban correctamente me da el mismo error.

Servidor:

```
    const express = require('express')
    const cors = require('cors')
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    
    require('dotenv').config()
    
    const app = express()
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
    
    app.use(cors())
    app.use(express.json())
    
    mongoose
        .connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/justwatch',{useNewUrlParser:true})
        .catch(e=>console.log('Connection error:',e.message))
    
    const connection = mongoose.connection
    connection.once('open',()=>{
        console.log('MongoDB MOVIES database connection successfully');
    })
    
    const movieRouter = require('./routes/movie')
    const seriesRouter = require('./routes/serie')
    
    app.use('/movies',movieRouter)
    app.use('/series',seriesRouter)
    
    app.listen(port,()=>{console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`)})
```

Router:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
let Movie = require('../models/movie.model')

router.route('/movies').get((req,res)=>{

let limite = parseInt(req.params.number)

Movie.find().limit(12)
    .then(movies=>res.json(movies))
    .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('Error: '+err))
})

router.route('/').get((req,res)=>{

Movie.find().limit(12)
        .then(movies=>res.json(movies))
        .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('Error: '+err))
})
module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1):

El error radica en que el endpoint movies lo está llamando 2 veces, uno en el router y el otro dentro del servidor. debería ser algo como esto:

Router (movies):

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const Movie = require('../models/movie.model')

router.get('/', (req,res)=>{

const limite = parseInt(req.params.number)

Movie.find().limit(limite)
    .then(movies=>res.json(movies))
    .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('Error: '+err))
})

module.exports = router
```

Para el router de series haría un módulo semejante al anterior y listo.

Si es que lo quiere implementar de esta manera.